# Unable to run Notepad++ after installation

Tags: installation

What can be done to run this program - NOTEPAD++ after installation.
What may be the cause of it ?
A blue dialogue box pop up as shown.

[image]

Comment: Talk to your IT administrator

Comment: Thanks. I run it as administrator. It works now.

Comment: It's running from a temp folder and there are policies OK your computer preventing that. Did you install it for all users? Did you just download a portable installer and its in the temp folders? You haven't solved the problem, you've only hidden it by using an unsafe method of use. Running as admin should be reserved for only systems for which it is required. It should not be necessary to run Notepad++ as admin.